# xmonad --recompile without xmessage errors

Tags: xmonad

When I make changes to `xmonad.hs`, I almost always make syntax errors at first try (I guess haskell syntax is too cryptic for me, but Xmonad is too good a tool to give up). When I `xmonad --recompile` in a terminal, these errors are listed in my terminal, which is useful. But they also are listed in a crappy, annoying `xmessage` window which pops up, how can I avoid this?

---

Edit: I haven't seen the problem for some time now on my distribution, I guess developers caught the redundancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this is hardcoded into the XMonad `recompile` function at this time.

- [xmessage call in XMonad/Core.hs](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/577d5ae968d5c87f311b79cd6267f4c7aec27dd7/src/XMonad/Core.hs#L490)

Comment: Thanks. Any chance this will get removed in a future release, or is it useful for too many people? Is it worth asking developers?

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to be worked around by appending a noop implementation of `xmessage` to your PATH when you run `xmonad`! In most cases something like the following should work:

```bash
tmp=$(mktemp -d)
touch $tmp/xmessage
chmod +x $tmp/xmessage
```

Now run

```bash
PATH="$PATH:$tmp" xmonad --recompile
```

To recompile with no `xmessage` dialogue!

For Nix users like me, the steps might be different. In my case the file `$(which xmonad)` explicitly defines a `XMONAD_MESSAGE` env var pointing to the `xmessage` build in the Nix store, and so my fix looked something like this:

```bash
tmp=$(mktemp -d)
touch $tmp/xmessage
chmod +x $tmp/xmessage
cp $(which xmonad) > ./xmonad
# edit ./xmonad to change XMONAD_MESSAGE to set it to $tmp/xmonad
chmod +x ./xmonad
# now we can run:
./xmonad --recompile
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I haven't seen the problem for some time now on my distribution, I guess developers caught the redundancy.